# Service can't starts Mounts Denied

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, macos, docker, docker-compose

I m using Mac and tring to build catalog.api with mongo db. But I'm getting error that "Service can't start service CatalogDB:Mounts denied"

Googled and trying to add the the below line in docker's file sharing

/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder

Catalog.Api created and running but mongo db is failing

docker-compose.yml

version: '3.4'

services:

catalogdb:

```
image: mongo
```

catalog.api:

```
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}catalog

build:

  context: .

  dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
```

Docker-compose.override.yml

version: '3.4'

services:

catalogdb:

```
container_name: catalogdb

restart: always

volumes:

      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site:/data/db

ports:

    - "27017:27017"
```

catalog.api:

```
environment:

  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

  - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80

  - "CatalogDatabaseSettings:ConnectionString=mongodb://catalogdb:27017"

depends_on:

   - catalogdb

ports:

  - "8000:80"

  - "8001:443"

volumes:

  - ~/.aspnet/https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro

  - ~/.microsoft/usersecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
```

what I m missing or doing anything wrong. any help appreciated

Mahendra

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue - did you manage to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue. Disabling "Use gRPC FUSE for file sharing" fixes it.